# Type mismatch when trying to declare custom typeface

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fonts, android-typeface

When using a custom typeface in a settings fragment which context needs be used in this scenario? I know that `this` needs to be change but I couldn't find any relevant tutorials on this.

> Type mismatch. Required: Context. Found: SettingsFragment

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
    }

    private val mTypeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.open_dyslexic_regular)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Activities, Fragments are not subclasses of Context. You'll see many Android tutorials where `this` is passed as the Context argument to some function, and that's because they are calling that code from inside an Activity instead of from a Fragment.

Fragments have a `context` property you can use, but it is `null` before the Fragment gets attached to an Activity (like when the class is initialized) and after it is detached.

You can use the `lazy` property delegate, so the context will not be null when the `getFont` function is called. But if you do this, don't access the property from a callback that could be called after the fragment is detached.

```
private val mTypeface by lazy { ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.open_dyslexic_regular) }
```

Comment: `Type mismatch. Required: Context. Found: Context?`

Comment: Oops, you can use `requireContext()` instead (or just `context!!`). This returns a non-nullable `context` and throws an exception if `context` is currently null. But it won't be so long as this property is only accessed from lifecycle methods and not from callbacks that could be called while the fragment is detached (like in a network access callback).

Answer (score 0):

In fragment you can call getContext or getActivity instead of pass this when get custom font. But your code will be crash because when fragment not attach to host context is null try to change

```
private val mTypeface : Typeface get() = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.open_dyslexic_regular)
```

Comment: `requireContext` throws an exception if `context` is currently null.

Comment: No unless you call before fragment onCreate. It means your code is bug

Comment: In this code, you are calling it before onCreate, because it is part of the class initialization.

Comment: I already put get() after type it will be create when you call. It never crash

Comment: Ah, I missed that.